# Selector in Directives

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

The following directive should hide an element.

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
import {el} from "@angular/platform-browser/testing/src/browser_util";

// Directive decorator
@Directive({ selector: '[hide-me]' })
// Directive class
export class MyHiddenDirective {
//  @Input() hideme:boolean;
  constructor(public el: ElementRef, public  renderer: Renderer2) {
    // Use renderer to render the element with styles
        renderer.setStyle(el.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');

  }
}
```

I am using it as follows:

```
<div>Name: <input hide-me #myint  type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="this.name" />  You entered {{this.name}} {{myint.hasAttribute('required')}}</div>
```

Why does `selector: '[hide-me]'` work but `selector: 'hide-me'` doesn't? I do not use square brackes when I use the Directive `<input hide-me...` and not `<input [hide-me]...`. In Components, we generally specify selector without square brackets. Why do I need to specify square brackets in Directives?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because the selector is a CSS selector. The same kind of selector you use in a CSS file to specify which elements are concerned by a CSS rule:

- `foo` means elements with name `foo`
- `[foo]` means elements with an attribute named `foo`
- `.foo` means elements with a CSS class named `foo`
- `foo[bar]` means elements named foo with an attribute named `bar`, etc.

**As a complement**
The *directive*'s *selector* can be used as an *input* which is especially useful when that input carries something other than a boolean (as the directive instance suffices to tell it is active), use the [@Input decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/Input)'s "bindingPropertyName" argument to use distinct tokens between the template attribute and the Directive class property:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[enhanced-me]' })
export class NodeEnhancementDirective {
  @Input('enhanced-me') options: {foo: true, bar: true} ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. regarding `foo[bar]`, my selector in directive is `[hide-me]` and I have an attribute in class `@Input() hideme:boolean`. But I am unable to use it as `<input hide-me[hideme]="true"..` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `[hideme]` as selector, and `<input [hideme]="true">`

Comment: got error = `Angular: Can't bind to 'hideme' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.`

Comment: You probably forgot to declare your directive. See http://plnkr.co/edit/O77pgTgWvb0eZBfif0h7?p=preview: it works fine.

Comment: The declaration was already there. Things got working when I changed the selector from `[hide-me]` to `[hideme]`. This seems strange!

Comment: So, things started working when doing what I precisely told you to do: *Use [hideme] as selector*. Why do you expect [hideme]="true" to select your directive if its selector is [hide-me]?

Comment: my bad, didn't read that one properly. But things didn't work when my selector was `[hide-me]` and the property was `hideme`. If my selector is `S` and I have properties `P1` and `P2`, how to do assign values to these properties?

Comment: `<div S [P1]="..." [P2]="...">`. P1 and P2 mustbe inputs, not just properties.

Comment: ah! found the issue. I didn't keep a space earlier. `hide-me [hideme]` works, `hide-me[hideme]` doesn't. you might want to change your answer above and add space between foo and [bar]

Comment: For anyone that may get wrong directions here: the error wasn't because of the space between elements. It was just because of the wrong use of the directive trigger itself. If the directive was declared with the selector "[hide-me]", the element where it will be triggered MUST HAVE an ATTRIBUTE "hide-me". Following your last comment, @ManuChadha: you didn't needed the "[hideme]" sentence at all, because all the work was done by the "hide-me" one.